# Set paramaters of Cooja Simulation

Tags: contiki, cooja

I'm trying to do some simulation of the RPL protocol using Contiki 3.0 and the Cooja Simulator. I'm using the sky motes and i'd like to see how the DODAG is formed and monitor the parameters of the network using the Collect View. I have some questions:

1) Where and how i can change the Objective function?

2) My sensors have 1mW energy consumption, i think that for real application is too much, since sensors needs to work for several years

3) Where i can change the other parameters of the simulation? Like Tx/Rx packets?

4) How I interpret the routing metric given in the collect view?

5) I noticed that when I change the position of a node the network is too much slow detecting the movement, RPL is not very fast, but in Cooja it takes too much time, is it possible? Do you have any suggestion for simulating moving sensors?

Comment: First of all - one question at the time, please! See the [help] on how to ask questions that can be answered here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your can set change objective function from contiki/core/net/rpl/rpl-conf.h

edit as per your requirement:

```
/*
 * The objective function (OF) used by a RPL root is configurable through
 * the RPL_CONF_OF_OCP parameter. This is defined as the objective code
 * point (OCP) of the OF, RPL_OCP_OF0 or RPL_OCP_MRHOF. This flag is of
 * no relevance to non-root nodes, which run the OF advertised in the
 * instance they join.
 * Make sure the selected of is inRPL_SUPPORTED_OFS.
 */
#ifdef RPL_CONF_OF_OCP
#define RPL_OF_OCP RPL_CONF_OF_OCP
#else /* RPL_CONF_OF_OCP */
#define RPL_OF_OCP RPL_OCP_MRHOF
#endif /* RPL_CONF_OF_OCP */

/*
 * The set of objective functions supported at runtime. Nodes are only
 * able to join instances that advertise an OF in this set. To include
 * both OF0 and MRHOF, use {&rpl_of0, &rpl_mrhof}.
 */
#ifdef RPL_CONF_SUPPORTED_OFS
#define RPL_SUPPORTED_OFS RPL_CONF_SUPPORTED_OFS
#else /* RPL_CONF_SUPPORTED_OFS */
#define RPL_SUPPORTED_OFS {&rpl_mrhof}
#endif /* RPL_CONF_SUPPORTED_OFS */

/*
 * Enable/disable RPL Metric Containers (MC). The actual MC in use
 * for a given DODAG is decided at runtime, when joining. Note that
 * OF0 (RFC6552) operates without MC, and so does MRHOF (RFC6719) when
 * used with ETX as a metric (the rank is the metric). We disable MC
 * by default, but note it must be enabled to support joining a DODAG
 * that requires MC (e.g., MRHOF with a metric other than ETX).
 */
#ifdef RPL_CONF_WITH_MC
#define RPL_WITH_MC RPL_CONF_WITH_MC
#else /* RPL_CONF_WITH_MC */
#define RPL_WITH_MC 0
#endif /* RPL_CONF_WITH_MC */
```

2) Contiki provides radio duty cycle (RDC) mechanisms for long term operation of nodes.
Default is nullrdc in which node always remains on hence life is less. Set ContikiMAC for minimizing power of nodes.
goto contiki/core/contiki-default-conf.h and edit as per your requirement.

e.g.

```
#ifndef NETSTACK_CONF_RDC
/* #define NETSTACK_CONF_RDC   nullrdc_driver */
#define NETSTACK_CONF_RDC   contikimac_driver 
#endif /* NETSTACK_CONF_RDC */
```

3) Tx/Rx can be set from Network visualizer itself. You can right click any node and edit tx/rx range as well as success ratio.
You can also edit the same in .csc (simulation) file.

```
    <radiomedium>
      org.contikios.cooja.radiomediums.UDGM
      <transmitting_range>100.0</transmitting_range>
      <interference_range>120.0</interference_range>
      <success_ratio_tx>0.9</success_ratio_tx>
      <success_ratio_rx>0.9</success_ratio_rx>
    </radiomedium>
```

4) You have to calculate various performance metrics. For that you have code script file yourself (tough part).
Or use these links
https://github.com/iloveyii/contiki_rpl/tree/master/perl

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d319/4d5f43f1cd3995ba7c9e99776ac8f150d445.pdf

5) Use mobility plugin to simulate various mobility models.

https://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/Mobility_of_Nodes_in_Cooja

http://vrajesh2188.blogspot.com/2016/04/mobility-in-contiki-2.html

Comment: What do you think about 1mW instantaneous power consumption? And a very low duty cycle, sensors sleep for 99% of the time!

Comment: Duty cycling save power. Initially when a node starts it has lot of broadcasts in order to setup the network at that point power consumption is high. Later with duty cycling nodes mostly sleeps during no TX/RX.

Comment: Is it possible having a duty cycle of only 0.5% ?? It seems a very few time. It count only the time used by the RPL protocol? If for example I have a full protocol stack, in a real scenario, how does the duty cycle changes?

Comment: yes it is possible in case of Low Power and Lossy Networks and Trickle Algorithm used by RPL protocol. Nodes most of the sleep and don't transmit once they are part of the DODAG and stable topology. If you want more details how this is possibe and what RDC is ? then go through contiki's manuals and codes.